# WSO2 - value dynamically injected to the endpoint

Tags: endpoint, wso2-esb

I am a newbie in WSO2 ESB and I am struggling with one issue related to the dynamically generated endpoint adress uris.

I followed by the [tutorial](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport) how to integrate RabbitMQ with WSO2 and I created following endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test2">
        <address trace="disable" uri="rabbitmq:/Test?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=test&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=test&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=amq.direct&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json" />
</endpoint>
```

However, I wanted to inject dynamically value of rabbitmq.server.host.name, so I created a *local entry*, like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <localEntry key="queue.hostname" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><![CDATA[localhost]]></localEntry>
```

and injected that value to the endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test2">
    <property expression="get-property('queue.hostname')" name="queue.hostname" scope="default" type="STRING" />
    <address trace="disable" uri="rabbitmq:/Test?rabbitmq.server.host.name={queue.hostname}&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=test&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=test&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=amq.direct&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json" />
</endpoint>
```

During tests, I discovered that property queue.hostname value in not correctly injected to the URI and URI is:

```
rabbitmq:/Test?rabbitmq.server.host.name={queue.hostname}&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=test&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=test&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=amq.direct&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json
```

instead of:

```
rabbitmq:/Test?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=test&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=test&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=amq.direct&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=outputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json
```

Do you know what I am doing wrong? 
I will apreciate any example codes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the ESB version you use?

Comment: wso2esb-5.0.0-beta, but i can easily switch to the wso2esb-5.0.0-beta2 if it will be needed

Answer (score 1):

As you take values from property mediator, it can't assign in the middle of URI as it does not take parameter values. So you have to use endpoint templates for that.

Sample scenario:

```
<template xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TM_out_endpoint_template">
   <axis2ns158:parameter xmlns:axis2ns158="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="host">        </axis2ns158:parameter>
<endpoint name="$name">
  <address uri="jms:/MyQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://$host:61616&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue">
     <suspendOnFailure>
        <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
     </suspendOnFailure>
     <markForSuspension>
        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
        <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
     </markForSuspension>
     </address>
   </endpoint>
</template>
```

Use that according to your scenario. Reference: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Endpoint+Template

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will test it. To be honest I was looking for description of tag called axis2ns158 and I couldn't find anything interesting. How did you know that we should use that tag?

Comment: It will be added by synapse (for its reference) when you adding parameters in endpoint template. You don't need to add it forcefully. U can test this through Management Console.